# Remove multiple levels of directory while extracting from zipfile python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a zipfile that when I extract using `ZipFile.extract(member[, path[, pwd]])¶` the file gets extracted in multiple levels of directory. Is it probably because of the way it was zipped.

```
--Level1-Dir
   --Level2-Dir
    --Level3-Dir
     --actualfile
```

Is it possible to extract the actual file at first level? If yes, is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
import zipfile

f = zipfile.ZipFile("x.zip")

for i in f.namelist():
    if not i.endswith("/"):
        print f.open(i).read()
```

Comment: This would not extract the file. May be if I write the file it would do the job. But I want to extract.